# Presto how to tune the task.max-worker-threads parameter according to lscpu

Tags: presto

in presto document the definition of - **task.max-worker-threads** is:

---

Type: integer

Default value: Node CPUs * 2

### *`Sets the number of threads used by workers to process splits. Increasing this number can improve throughput if worker CPU utilization is low and all the threads are in use,`*

is it mean that ?

{`number of CPU`} X {`Thread(s) per core`}

for example

```
lscpu
Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                16 <--
On-line CPU(s) list:   0-15
Thread(s) per core:    1 <--
Core(s) per socket:    16
Socket(s):             1
```

so do we need to set ? ( according to lscpu )

```
task.max-worker-threads=16
```

other example

```
lscpu
Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                16 <--
On-line CPU(s) list:   0-15
Thread(s) per core:    2 <--
Core(s) per socket:    16
Socket(s):             1
```

in this case my guess is we need to set ? ( 16 X 2 )

task.max-worker-threads=32

am I right?

the configuration file with task.max-worker-threads

```
more  config.properties

coordinator=false
http-server.http.port=1010
task.max-worker-threads=$VAL
discovery.uri=http://coordinator01:1010
```

Comment: Default value is calculated based on number of CPU cores. Usually you don't need to set this setting. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Dear Piotr Findeisen  - see please my update , we need to set the value for the parameter - task.max-worker-threads , so according to what you said we need to set $VAL to 16? ( based on my lscpu output )

Comment: Why don't you remove that line from the config file?

Comment: if I remove it , then what is the value that presto will use? second back to my orig question lets say I want to use this line then what is the value that I should set according to lscpu?