# Presto dashboard + presto workers machines are not stable

Tags: presto, trino

We noticed about the following strange behavior in our presto cluster ( presto installed on Linux machines )

We have 9 presto workers machines ,

And from the presto dashboard we can see that some time there are `7-8` active workers and some time all presto workers - `9`

**is it normal behavior ?**

From the presto workers logs I cant see something unusual

And I not sure if we need to searched any network problem or any other issue ?

[image]

Note - when I restart all presto workers , then after restart the presto workers are stable on the dashboard , but after `5-10` Hours we get again the strange behavior again  , we are Helpless with this situation ,

Note1 - we check if presto binaries restart in accidentally - but this isnt the case , all presto workers binaries are stable

```
./launcher status
Running as 22815
```

*I must to said additionally that Presto dashboard not show which of the presto workers was down , so this is very difficult to understand which are the "bad" presto workers ,*

*** in the presto coordinator log- we can see message like this:

```
- but not sure this are related to our issues? 

WARN    http-client-memoryManager-scheduler     com.facebook.presto.memory.RemoteNodeMemory     Error fetching memory info from http://105.14.25.4:1010/v1/memory: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Total timeout 10000 ms elapsed
```

Comment: This isn't a normal behavior, something is not working as it supposed to be. You may want to ask for troubleshooting advice on `#troubleshooting` in Presto Community Slack (https://prestosql.io/community.html).

Comment: in that case , do you have direction ? or some hint ? , I think the community will answer after some time , and stack-overflow is place that we get fast answers -:)

Comment: If only I knew the answer... You need to check the logs of the coordinator and the workers and search for anything abnormal. Community can help understand the meaning and significance of logs (especially that creators of Presto are active there).

Comment: OK , I will bth - can you please advice me on this thread - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57392597/presto-how-to-tune-the-task-max-worker-threads-parameter-according-to-lscpu

Comment: Dear - @Piotr Findeisen  , please see my update in the question , maybe this is realted to mu issue?

Comment: Dear  @Piotr Findeisen , please see my answer , I am so sorry about wasting your time because my silly mistake

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i am so apologize for the inconvenience , about my question

actually this is my mistake and I will explain

in this presto cluster we have 9 presto workers

**but I forget to delete the same host name workers from other cluster**

so this behavior is because 3 duplicate host names ( presto workers )

after removing the duplicate presto workers , now presto is very stable